# Facebook, Post to Wall customize screen

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, feed, facebook-wall

Im looking for a way to customize the standard "Feed Dialog" screen the Graph API offers.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

The idea is that the Feed Dialog matches the layout of my application and not the standard Facebook layout.

First thought was creating a seperate Dialog Box, which offers the same functionalities as the original box and passing that to the function which posts everything on the users wall.

But I am unable to find a way to implement the textarea, that gives Users the ability to enter aditional text to post.

Anyone who knows if this is possible and can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your own interface for posting to facebook, don't use their dialog. Create your own form however you like, and then submit the information with

```
FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: myMessage }, function(response) {
});
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/